# "How to plot a 3D bar plot in Julia"

Tags: 3d, julia, bar-chart

I want to plot a 3D bar plot in Julia.

I am working with Julia 1.0.4. I've already tried this: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/plotting-3d-bar-graph/12735
But it doesn't work for me and I get errors.

```
vector = zeros(3,5)
vector[:,1] = [2,3,3]
vector[:,2] = [3,5,6]
vector[:,3] = [4,5,8]
vector[:,4] = [5,7,10]
vector[:,5] = [6,6,12]
```

Let's say each row in this vector is a node (i.e., node1, node2, node3) and each columns shows the size of that node in one timestep. I want to have a barplot that shows the amount of each node in each timestep as a bar (the picture is just an example that I copy and pasted from google images):

[image]

Comment: Makie's meshscatter function is probably your best bet, so I'd suggest you comment on the linked discourse post. BTW, a 3d bar plot is a terrible way to show your data :-)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelK.Borregaard . That's what I was thinking about, a grouped bar plot seems to be better :)